# How to pass custom facelet tag attr to implementation in JSF 2

Tags: jsf-2

I have the next:

**/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<webapp>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/my-taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</webapp>
```

**/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/my-tablib.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
                version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://example.com/jsf/taglib</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>my-tag</tag-name>
        <!-- /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/com/example/myTag.xml -->
        <source>tags/com/example/myTag.xml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/com/example/myTag.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="customAttr" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.customAttr}" />
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

**/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:exui="http://example.com/jsf/taglib">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <exui:my-tag customAttr="showMe" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

As the result, I don't see "showMe" message after war was deployed. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You put the composite component in `/resources/<composite name>` folder(no need to add `my-tablib.xml` to `web.xml`), 
for example:

[image]

and then you can use by declare:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          ...
          xmlns:cps="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composites/CPSI35"
          >
          ...
          <cps:cpscontact ....></cps:cpscontact>
```